CSS - Sub menu getting hidden behind the main content
<style>
nav {
            width: 15%; /* Decreased width */
            background-color: silver; /* Silver */
            color: #333;
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 100vh; /* Set height to 100% of the viewport height */
            position: fixed; /* Fixed position to keep the menu on the screen */
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add scroll if content exceeds height */
            
        }

nav ul{
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a{
display : flex;
align-items :  center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 1.15em;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
color: #000;
padding: 10x 30px;
height: 50px;
transition: .5s ease;[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/LhoWh10d.png)
border-radius: 0 30px;
}


nav ul .dropdown{
position : relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
color: #fff;
}


nav ul ul{
position: absolute;
left: 250px;
width :200px;
top: 0;
display: none;
background: rgba(155,39,176,.4);
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
z-index: 1;
} 

nav ul ul span{
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
font-size: 1.5em;
} 


nav ul .dropdown:hover ul {
    display: initial;
}  
    
</style>

</head>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Dashboard')">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Sales')">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Purchases')">Purchases</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Products')">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Payments')">Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Inventory')">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Accounts')">Accounts</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Collection')">Collection</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Reports')">Reports<span>&rsaquo;</span> </a>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Ledger')">Ledger</a></li>                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Inventory')">Inventory</a></li>                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Purchases')">Purchases</a></li>
</ul>
</li> 
</ul>
</nav>

<section id="main-content">
    <!-- Default content -->
    <h1>Welcome to the Billing Software</h1>
    <p>Select an option on the left to view specific content.</p>
</section>

when i click on "Reports" a right side sub menu should get rendered with the options ledgers, inventory and purchases. The sub menu is getting rendered but it is HIDDEN behind the "main-content" area instead it should be visible on top.
how can we achieve this?

Please add enough code to create a [mre]

Hi! I can't reproduce your problem, but I think the solution is using a "z-index: 2;" or higher in your css.

I believe you are trying to have an overlay menu on top of the main content of the page with a scroll-y property that shows another menu on the same overlay.
If this is true. Then the issue is that the main nav element has a width of 15%. When you add the sub menu of width 200px it simply has no space to be displayed in and as it is absolute it disappears and can't be fixed by setting the z-axis only.
To fix this you would like to have a larger x-axis i.e width to be able to display it.
We can do that to an element behind the main nav element and give it 100vw to display all the content while still not affecting your design so we give it transparent background to see the text in the background. We will also give this element the scroll property on y-axis in case you added more items.
Here's the answer


* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh; /* Set height to 100% of the viewport height */
            position: absolute;
            position: fixed; /* Fixed position to keep the menu on the screen */
            z-index: 0;
            overflow-y: scroll;

        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .main-content {
            position:fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .main-nav {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.682);
            color: #333;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 20%;
            min-width: 200px;
            z-index: 1

        }

        nav ul li a{
            display : flex;
            align-items :  center;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 1.15em;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            color: #000;
            /* padding: 10x 30px; */
            height: 50px;
            /* transition: .5s ease;[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/LhoWh10d.png) */
            border-radius: 0 30px;
        }

        nav ul li a:hover{
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            color: #fff;
        }

        .main-nav li {
            margin: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
        }

        /* nav ul ul{ */
        .dropdown ul {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            left: 50px;
            width :200px;
            /* display: none; */
            background: rgba(155, 39, 176, 0.893);
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            z-index: 2;
        }

        nav ul ul span{
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        } 


        nav ul .dropdown:hover ul {
            display: initial;
        }
<div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Dashboard')">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Sales')">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Purchases')">Purchases</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Products')">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Payments')">Payments</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Inventory')">Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Accounts')">Accounts</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Collection')">Collection</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Reports')">Reports
                        <span>&rsaquo;</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Ledger')">Ledger</a></li>                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Inventory')">Inventory</a></li>                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeContent('Purchases')">Purchases</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">other item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section class="main-content">
            <!-- Default content -->
            <h1>Welcome to the Billing Software</h1>
            <p>Select an option on the left to view specific content.</p>
        </section>
    </div>



